# Trim date format PrimeNG calendar - remove timestamp, angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have the following pushed into my reactive forms obj `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`
but I want the following `2016-01-01`.

Does anyone know of a built in function to achieve the above. I've searched the docs [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) but no luck. A [.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) would of course work fine in a callback, but I'm wondering if anyone has done this before and knows a built in
functionality.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To help others - this is how I solved it with the help of the answer below using primeng calender, reactive forms in angular. Using `(onSelect)` callback specific to [primeNg Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

<p-calendar
    #purchaseDateRef
    (onSelect)="handleSelect(purchaseDateRef)">
</p-calendar>


constructor(
    private datePipe: DatePipe
) {}

handleSelect(event: any) {
  // manipulate date object with help of DatePipe and setValue
  this.form.get('registrationFields.appliance.purchaseDate')
     .setValue(this.datePipe.transform(event.value, 'y.MM.dd')
  );
}
```

Comment: How do you handle when the content of the date field is cleared? (In this case the `handleSelect` isn't called and the value remains)

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt - it's been a while since I looked at this project but you could play around with either a `(change)="handleSelect($event)"` or `(onChange)="handleSelect($event)"` and check to see if the field has content `if(event.value === '')`

Comment: `(change)="handleSelect($event)"` it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject DatePipe in your component, as

constructor( private datePipe: DatePipe){}

than you can use wherever in the component the transform function

const formattedDate = this.datePipe.transformer(dateValue, 'build_in_date_format')

there are many build in formats, refer to the official documentation https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe