# manipulate angular reactive form field object before it gets set

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in Angular.

I want to manipulate the date object but getting the following error with the below code.

`Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

Is there a way to see the value using reactive forms.

```
<p-calendar
    #purchaseDateRef
    (onSelect)="handleSelect(purchaseDateRef)">
</p-calendar>


handleSelect(event: any) {
     this.form.get('registrationFields.appliance.purchaseDate').value = event.value;
}
```

Comment: use `setValue` or `patchValue` :) https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: Thanks! This helped complete the following issue for anyone interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056693/trim-date-format-primeng-calendar-remove-timestamp-angular-reactive-forms